# Is there a syntax in Elisp for indexed getters and setters?

Tags: syntax, data-structures

I want to define a struct for chores

```
(defstruct chore name sector assignments)
```

where the `assignments` slot is a vector with seven positions. I know that the above syntax will generate the getters `chore-name`, `chore-sector` and `chore-assignments`. But I would like to have something like this `(chore-assignment 1 c)`. Is there any syntax that will give me this “for free” or should I code the function myself?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes and no. No, because `chore-assignment` doesn't let you modify what's inside the value of the assignment slot; it only lets you modify the assignment slot itself.

Instead, Lisp has `setf`, which has some really good tricks up its sleeves. The first argument to `setf` is a `PLACE`, which is any expression which can be interpreted as a place to store a value. Often this is just a variable name, but it can be much more complex. Just based on your question, I think you've already been using something like this:

```
(setf (chore-assignments c) (vector foo bar baz))
```

You can also do more:

```
(setf (aref (chore-assignments c) 1) 42)
```

Note that the `PLACE` in this assignment is not the whole assignments vector, it's one individual element inside the vector, exactly as you wanted.